# Magento. Extremely low First Byte and load time

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I am not a specialist, and even after scouring the web for answers and optimization tips, I couldn't really find a solution to my issue. Before Hiring a specialist, I would like to ask for some help first in this excellent community.

We installed a month ago our magento website: [www.skinfactory.com.ar](http://www.skinfactory.com.ar)
We used to run an old version of magento in the past with no issues at all.

The thing is that since we installed the new version (and a new template too) performance is unacceptable. speed test results are really, but really poor (Load time `26s` and First Byte `17s` ) -yes seconds!-

We are hosting at siteground with `17 x 3.0 GHz CPU Cores, CentOS, 12GB RAM, 20GB SSD`, which I think that is more than enough.

We have 2000 visits per day and 3000 products installed, which I also think is moderate comparing to bigger sites.

Hosting tech team says the server is overloaded most of the time consuming excessive resources. The also say that there are some queries on the database slowering all the process.

Our products (cell phone skins) are offered for around 200 different cell phones and we achieve that with simple products Mageworx Options Template. (We create the options and assign them to products).

Anyone on the community could help us? We have already tried some classic optimisation tricks for the images and merged java but nothing gives the site a better performance.

*update. I dont know if it helps, but I got this results from webpagetest.org

```
TTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 29 Mar 2015 19:12:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d67ee194d0f1f1a2b77ddb6c49f4a94d61427656287; expires=Mon, 28-Mar-16 19:11:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.skinfactory.com.ar; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.33
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: frontend=9dfb6b90506edb49ba536438ba152dbe; expires=Sun, 29-Mar-2015 20:11:30 GMT; path=/; domain=www.skinfactory.com.ar; HttpOnly
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.7.30.5-3847
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Host-Header: 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Server: cloudflare-nginx
```

CF-RAY: 1cede177eb97188e-EWR
Content-Encoding: gzip

Comment: you  need to debug your system.Check system.log and excpetion magento/var/log folder.Check cache is enable or not

Answer (score 1):

Themes can definitely be a cause of performance issues, I have seen this a lot. Try searching in the theme folder for "->load(". A common cause of performance problems I have found is where a themer loads a product collection loops through it and then calls ->load on the product to load more data. If there  are 200 products, thats 200 db queries instead of one. Product collections are just one example though.

Answer (score 0):

For me it appears that not much has changed apart from a new Magento version. The new Magento version shouldn't give you any additional performance issues.

The other thing that I notice that has changed is the theme, was this a purchased theme? I have had many bad experiencing with purchased themes performing horrible code which results in poor performance.

Do you have a developement site on the same server? If not, get one. Then try with the default RWD theme and see what the TTFB is.

If nothing else has changed my guess would be the theme.

Comment: Thanks for your help, we will check going back to defaul theme to see if that is the problem

Comment: does this data help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's profiler to troubleshoot performance issues.

There are articles [here](http://www.neptuneweb.com/blog/24-identifying-magento-performance-problems-with-the-magento-profiler.html), [here](http://www.techawaken.com/enable-magento-profiler-identify-magento-performance-bottlenecks/) and [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/keeping-your-magento-fit-with-built-in-profiler/) which should help get you started troubleshooting.